# how to disable only 1 day after current date in datepicker date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

How to disable only 1 day after current date in datepicker date. Suppose if user select monday, then the soonest day they can select is wednesday for any other day instead of tuesday.

Like when we order product on monday, soonest day they can select for delivery is wednesday after 2 days difference.

Comment: post what you tryed .. where is your code..?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After trying much I achieved what you said. See the below code and Check if that is what you want.

```
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           var date=new Date(selected)
            day=date.getDate()+2;
            newDate=date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + day + "/" + date.getFullYear();
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", newDate);


        }
    });
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CkfDP/1492/)**